# Stability of Hölder continuity under nonlinear maps

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion, harmonic-analysis

Let $f, g \in C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R})$ be Hölder continuous of degree $\alpha$ and let $F \in C^2_b$ be a bounded, twice continuously differentiable function with bounded derivatives. I would like to show that then also $F(f) - F(g) \in C^{\alpha}$ with an estimate in the direction of
$$\|F(f) - F(g)\|_{C^{\alpha}} \leq C(1 + \|f\|_{C^{\alpha}})(1 + \|g\|_{C^{\alpha}}) \|f-g\|_{\alpha}.$$
Here the fact that $F$ is really 'twice' continuously differentiable should be very important. Maybe it is also necessary that, moreover, $F''$ is Hölder continous of degree $\epsilon$.
Unfortunately, I couldn't make out at which point I would be able to exploit this. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does $C_2^b$ mean that the derivatives are bounded?

Comment: Yes, it does. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the notation
$$
\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n}|f(x)|,\quad\|f\|_\alpha=\|f\|_\infty+\sup_{x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}.
$$
Using the mean value theorem is easy to see that
$$
\|F(f)\|_\alpha\le\|F\|_\infty+\|F'\|_\infty\|f\|_\alpha
$$
and
$$
\|F(f)-F(g)\|_\infty\le\|F'\|_\infty\|f-g\|_\infty.
$$
Now, given $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$ and $f,g\in C_b^\alpha$
\begin{align}
F(f(x))-F(g(x))&=F'(\xi)(f(x)-g(x)),\quad\xi\text{ between }f(x)\text{ and }g(x),\\
F(f(y))-F(g(y))&=F'(\eta)(f(y)-g(y)),\quad\eta\text{ between }f(y)\text{ and }g(y).
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
&|(F(f(x))-F(g(x)))-(F(f(y))-F(g(y)))|\\
&\qquad=|F'(\xi)(f(x)-g(x))-F'(\eta)(f(y)-g(y))|\\
&\qquad\le|F'(\xi)|((f(x)-g(x))-(f(y)-g(y)))|+|F'(\xi)-F'(\eta)|\,|f(y)-g(y)|\\
&\qquad\le\|F'\|_\infty\|f-g\|_\alpha|x-y|^\alpha+\|F''\|_\infty\|f-g\|_\infty|\xi-\eta|\\
&\qquad\le\|F'\|_\infty\|f-g\|_\alpha|x-y|^\alpha+\|F''\|_\infty\|f-g\|_\infty|(\|f\|_\alpha+\|g\|_\alpha)|x-y|^\alpha,
\end{align}
where in the last line I have used that $|\xi-\eta|\le|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the last step why exactly $|\xi - \eta| \leq (\|f\|_{\alpha} + \|g\|_{\alpha}) |x-y|^{\alpha}$ holds?

Comment: There was a typo in the last inequality. It is $$|\xi-\eta|\le|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|.$$

Comment: Sorry, but I only get $|\xi - \eta| \leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |g(x) - g(y)| + |f(y) - g(y)|$. I seem to be missing a crucial step here.

Comment: Use the fact that $\xi$ is between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and $\eta$ between $f(y)$ and $g(y)$. You can draw the different possibilities on a line, and convince yourself that the inequality holds. I have to admit that it took me a while to be convinced by this argument.